# Worksheet_ Change doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel, events

I have a problem with `Worksheet_Change`. When I target the cell Excel doesn't react at all even if I put an error in the code. I put the `Worksheet_Change` on the right sheet, so that's not the reason.

I simplified my code as much as I could and there is still no reaction.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$c$2" Then
        MsgBox "hi"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `=` is case sensitive =>> change `"$c$2"` to `"$C$2"`

Comment: Try `If Target.Address = Range("C2").Address Then`

Comment: if it doesnt react at all, then try `Stop` as first command in the sub and check if it gets highlighted... if not, put in your direct window `Application.EnableEvents = True` and try it again... and make sure you didn't hit the pause-button in your vba window

Comment: Tried every suggestion, but still no reaction to a change in the cell

Comment: Try with single line `MsgBox "hi"`  in your sub and nothing else.... :s

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Me.Range("C2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Great! Target is within the chosen range!"
    End If
End Sub
```

This works. I always use the above structure.

Comment: I tried your code but its still nothing happening, could it be a error in the program or system , or maybe a setting ?

Comment: Try Dirk Reichel's suggestion above: Application.EnableEvents = True

Comment: all the suggestions i've seen are correct. Restart excel, you might be in debug mode, many people panick because macros won't launch anymore, (you can also clic the (stop) square )...

Answer (score 0):

I think the event listener that you want to trigger is `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.

For `Worksheet_Change` to work, you need to type something in cell C3

Comment: Isnt that when you want a macro to run when you select a cell ?

Comment: Yes, im just guessing because you said "when i target the cell"

Comment: Perhaps macro is disabled? Again just guessing :s

Comment: I tried an other solution and its not working either, when i run the module-macro i want to call manually its no problem so macros in generell should be activated :D

Comment: Try Dirk Reichel suggestion. `Application.EnableEvents = True` Just need to run this one time and try ur code again